# Use the result from one column to make column names

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have select statement, something like:

```
select trim(time), type, count(1) from table                             
group by trim(time),type
```

The results are:

```
02.10.13    REZ1    1

02.10.13    REZ2    5

02.10.13    REZ3    3
```

Is it possible to make some select statement with some Oracle function to get the following result:

```
REZ1    REZ2    REZ3

1       5       3
```

So, results from one column are column names in the other statement, something like:

```
select ?SOMETHING? 
from (
select trim(time), type, count(1) 
from table                             
group by trim(time),type) s
```

Comment: Depending on which version of Oracle you are using, `pivot` may be available. See this article from Tim Hall's excellent site: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t(l_date, val, l_count)
AS
(SELECT to_date('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy'), 'REZ1'   , 1 FROM dual UNION
SELECT to_date('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy'), 'REZ2'   , 5 FROM dual UNION
SELECT to_date('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy'), 'REZ3'   , 3 FROM dual 
)

SELECT *
FROM
     ( SELECT  val, l_count FROM   t
     ) PIVOT (MAX(l_count) FOR (val) IN ('REZ1' REZ1,'REZ2' REZ2 ,'REZ3' REZ3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the SQL alternative for this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE type
                WHEN 'REZ1' THEN cnt
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS REZ1,
       MAX(CASE type
                WHEN 'REZ2' THEN cnt
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS REZ2,
       MAX(CASE type
                WHEN 'REZ3' THEN cnt
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS REZ3
  FROM (SELECT trim(time), type, count(1) as cnt FROM table
        GROUP BY trim(time), type);
```

Or even better:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE type
                 WHEN 'REZ1' THEN 1
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS REZ1,
       COUNT(CASE type
                 WHEN 'REZ2' THEN 1
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS REZ2,
       COUNT(CASE type
                 WHEN 'REZ3' THEN 1
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS REZ3
  FROM table;
```

OUTPUT:

```
REZ1 | REZ2 | REZ3
1    | 5    | 3
```

This is applicable when you know the values in the `type` column. Even `pivot`, which is available in 11g, requires you to know the values in the column in order to pivot this as described in ajmalmhd04's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 2nd column will not have any value other than REZ1..3 then following solution will transpose the table data and take care of repetition as well by adding up the values.

```
WITH t
 AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy') AS dt,
            'REZ1' AS typ,
            1 AS cnt
       FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE ('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy') AS dt,
            'REZ2' AS typ,
            5 AS cnt
       FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE ('02.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy') AS dt,
            'REZ3' AS typ,
            3 AS cnt
       FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE ('03.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy') AS dt,
            'REZ1' AS typ,
            7 AS cnt
       FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE ('03.10.13', 'dd.mm.yy') AS dt,
            'REZ2' AS typ,
            2 AS cnt
       FROM DUAL)
  SELECT dt,
     SUM (CASE WHEN typ = 'REZ1' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS "REZ1",
     SUM (CASE WHEN typ = 'REZ2' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS "REZ2",
     SUM (CASE WHEN typ = 'REZ3' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS "REZ3"
FROM t
GROUP BY dt;


DT              REZ1       REZ2       REZ3
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
02-OCT-13          1          5          3
03-OCT-13          7          2          0

2 rows selected.
```

Incase column#2 is going to have random values, probably some kind of cursor needs to use to tweak this query for considering dynamic columns.
I will try to post that if I able to get that designed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select trim(time), 
       count(decode(type, 'REZ1', 1)) AS REZ1,
       count(decode(type, 'REZ2', 1)) AS REZ2,
       count(decode(type, 'REZ3', 1)) AS REZ3
  from table                             
 group by trim(time)
```